# What is the difference between -Wl,--export-dynamic and -Wl,-export-dynamic (single vs double-dash)?

Tags: gcc, clang, ld, dynamic-linking, ldflags

A user of [xnec2c](https://forum.dlang.org/thread/l66o93$1mdr$1@digitalmars.com) was trying to build on OSX with clang and got this error:

```
gcc --pedantic -Wall -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fpie -Wno-overlength-strings -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGSEAL_ENABLE -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-honor-nans -fno-signed-zeros -fno-math-errno -Wl,--export-dynamic -Wl,--as-needed  -o xnec2c main.o mathlib.o measurements.o interface.o callbacks.o console.o callback_func.o calculations.o cmnd_edit.o geom_edit.o gnuplot.o draw.o draw_structure.o draw_radiation.o fields.o fork.o geometry.o ground.o xnec2c.o input.o matrix.o utils.o nec2_model.o network.o optimize.o plot_freqdata.o radiation.o rc_config.o shared.o somnec.o xnec2c-resources.o -L/opt/local/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  -lpthread -lm
ld: unknown option: --export-dynamic
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(FYI: [GTK Builder](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Builder.html#signal-handlers-and-function-pointers) needs the export-dynamic linking flag.)

[This discussion](https://forum.dlang.org/thread/l66o93$1mdr$1@digitalmars.com) suggests making the double-dash a single dash:

```
-AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic
+AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-export-dynamic
```

However the user found that, actually, it needs a single dash *and* an underscore (maybe, [still having trouble that could be related](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/issues/16#issuecomment-1319266981), but at least `ld` stopped barking about the option):

```
-AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic
+AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-export_dynamic
```

**Questions:**

- Does single-dash `-Wl,-export-dynamic` work in both GCC and Clang?
- Whats with the underscore version as `-Wl,-export_dynamic`?
- How compatible is that option with older (and newer) versions of the GCC/Clang stacks?
- Other considerations or best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Both GNU `ld` and LLVM `lld` take `--export-dynamic` flag
- `ld` that ships with OS X takes `-export_dynamic` flag
- This has nothing to do with `gcc` or `clang`, these only pass the flag along to the linker